# ViewModel property not accessible to asp-route-id

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In this table

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="10">
@foreach (var device in @Model.Devices)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@device.DeviceID</td>
        <td>@device.DeviceName</td>
        <td>@device.CALs</td>
        <td align="right">@device.UnlockedFrom.ToShortDateString()</td>
        <td align="right">@device.UnlockedTo.ToShortDateString()</td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="DeleteDevice"
               asp-controller="Manage"
               asp-route-id="@device.DeviceId">
                Delete
            </a>
        </td>
  </tr>
}
```

`<td>@device.DeviceID</td>` is fine but `asp-route-id="@device.DeviceId` gives a squiggly `device does not contain a definition for DeviceId`

The viewmodel exposes a collection of devices

```
public IEnumerable<Device> Devices { get; set; }
```

`Device` includes the following properties

```
    public int DeviceID { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public int CALs { get; set; }
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }
    public DateTime UnlockedFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime UnlockedTo { get; set; }
```

How do I make `DeviceId` available to pass to the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your property name is `DeviceID` , not `DeviceId`. The property name you pass as the value of the `asp-route-*` attribute is case sensitive.

Change your code to

```
<a asp-action="DeleteDevice"  asp-controller="Home"
                                              asp-route-id="@device.DeviceID">Delete </a>
```